# Expo push notification service

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, react-native-push-notification

Im trying to send push notification using expo notification service, can anyone give the code for it, how to get the tokens and all the other standard stuff, I have been trying to read the documentation but it is really confusing. The app is already on test flight, Also I don't want to eject.

I don't mind using Firebase, but the app doesn't have a user login pages. I don't mind any other method too.

Thanks for the help